# You have a draft for this topic pending approval

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-editor, documentation-drafts

I am trying to edit few of the topics in documentation. However while trying to submit changes for one of the topic there's a popup saying - "You have a draft for this topic pending approval."

When I click on the pending reviews, these are the edits done of some other topics on the same page, not this one. What does this signify.?

[image]

Additionally when I tried to cancel to go out of editor, it pops up error.

[image]

Comment: Can confirm I also have a stuck draft like this.

Comment: I've had the same problem: I added an introduction and then wanted to add a new example. I could not submit the new example as the introduction-review was still pending. I was able to save the example as a draft, but in the end I lost the whole example anyway because I navigated off the page when looking at the pending reviews.